# Horizontal day planner/scheduler (drag and drop) with angularJS

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, angularjs, telerik, angular-ui

I'm looking for a solution that would allow me to make a horizontal drag and drop day scheuler. I have been looking at [AngularJS UI-calendar](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-calendar/)'s day view and [Telerik Kendo UI Scheduler](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/scheduler/index)'s day view, but there dosen't seem to be an option to flip it from vertical to horizontal. I want hours to be placed on the x-axis instead of the usual y-axis.

Am I correct in my assumption that neither solution would allow me to accomplish that? If so any suggetion for a workaround/another solution?

Answer (score 2):

Just started looking at this myself. Looking at Telerik Kendo UI Schedule, they have a Timeline view that looks like it will fit a horizontal view.

http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/scheduler/timeline